# Azure Bot Service Sample AuthenticationBot Sign-in card not working (application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth)

Tags: azure, botframework

I am following this tutorial using the v4 SDK.

[Add authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Put simply, I click on the "Sign In" button from the OAuthPrompt card, a window pops up with the title "Sign In" and the screen is blank.  This is using the bot service emulator.

I could be wrong but I feel like it's something to do with the content type.

```
application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth
```

I wish I had more information to offer.

From the samples, I get the same outcome whether I use the BotAuthenticationMSGraph or AuthenticationBot example.

Comment: Double check your Oauth setup on Azure portal. A blank screen typically means there's something wrong with the token request or authorization URLs.

Comment: Is the emulator setup based on these instructions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#use-the-emulator-to-test-your-bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance.  I've managed to progress but am not fully over the line yet.  Maybe it's clearer for others, but for me, I followed what I thought were the instructions and did this:

1. [Create Azure AD v2 Application (apps.dev.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#to-create-an-azure-ad-v2-application)
2. [Create BOT Registration (Azure Portal)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#to-register-an-azure-ad-v2-application)

... but in step 1. above, it automatically creates the app for you when you create the "Bot Channels Registration" so step 2 of creating the application is not required  I created a second app and used that one in my settings and I think that's where I was going wrong.

Thanks for your help.

On another note, once the above was corrected and I removed myself from the company Wifi, it all came good.  Network blocking issue!